# Notification sounds don't interrupt background sound

Tags: iphone, notifications, headphones

On my phone I always have some background noise playing like sounds of nature. I am almost always wearing headphones.

My problem is that I can hear the ringtone both from the phone speakers and my headphones, but notification sounds just fuse together with my background noise and as a result, I never hear them.

How can I make notifications force background noise to stop playing (or pause)?